# Is there any differences to the subtraction order in squared error function?

Tags: math, deep-learning, neural-network, statistics, linear-algebra

I have a question about finding a saddle point of squared error function. So let's say there's a matrix of a target output, Y, and matrix of a real output, X.
So we got squared error function:

E = (Y-X)^t (Y-X)

But I also can rewrite this to:

(X-Y)^t(X-Y)
cause this returns same value.

But when it comes to partial derivative of X, they make different gradients. One is heading to the saddle point, but another one doesn't?
And can it also affect my project?

Comment: That is ***not*** the mean squared error. I think you're confusing "matrix multiplication" and "elementwise multiplication"

Comment: *"But when it comes to partial derivative of X, they make different gradients."* << Could you please show your calculation of the gradients? These two expressions are ***always equal***, so their gradients also should always be equal.

Comment: So I mean 1/M * (Y-X)^t (Y-X) gives a single number, and it is same as MSE.

Comment: And my calculation of these two equation is partial derivative of 1/M * (Y-X)^t (Y-X) with regard to X equals - 1/M(Y-X) and 1/M(X-Y)^t(X-Y) equals 1/M(X-Y). I am not good at math, so I’m asking you Are these two gradients heading different directions? Or is my calculation wrong…?

Comment: Wait, what are the shapes of X and Y?

Comment: Hint: -(Y-X) = -Y-(-X) = -Y+X = X-Y

Comment: Wait I was soooo stupid. I’m shamed. Why did I not think about this? I should delete this question. Appreciate it by the way.

Comment: Note that what I said about (Y-X)^t (Y-X) not being the mean squared error in general for X and Y **matrices** is true, but if they are column vectors then it's okay, it is the mean squared error.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention. They ARE column vectors. Thanks.